# how to modify height of a div when hover it and with transition (priority of CSS without Javascript)

Tags: css, css-transitions

This is the code

HTML

```
<div id="footmain">
    <div id="col1" class="mark"></div>
    <div id="col2" class="mark"></div>
    <div id="col3" class="mark"></div>
    <div id="col4" class="mark"></div>
</div>
```

see an example here with the CSS that I have:

http://jsfiddle.net/EtBKx/8/

I need to drop it down with transition, starting slowly, going fast, finish slowly.
jQuery is the last way, cause I want to be without JavaScript and for multiple browsers and CPU speeds.

To be compatible with tablets and smartphones, is better to have a trigger in the bottom right of each tab, with the both functions of hover and clicked?, or a <"a">Direction<"/a"> link that can be clicked once to drop and one more to go to the direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified your fiddle a bit:
http://jsfiddle.net/EtBKx/17/

basically all I added was

```
    *vendorprefix*-transition: height ease 1s;
```

"ease" defines an animation that starts slow, becomes fast and ends slow.
Oh and you had .mark :hover (with a space), which didn't work, .mark:hover is what you'll want.

More about transitions:
http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp

Comment: with your code, that is very good, i have this problem (maybe due to the relative position of the "col4"

http://jsfiddle.net/EtBKx/26/

i want all to be floating on the next content

Comment: You want col4 to also cover the content beneath? Then yes, changing it to position: absolute would do the trick, however since this also removes it from the documentflow, you will need to define a containing element with a fixed height (100px in your case) that is not removed from the documentflow.

Comment: ok, that was the solution, i made it by my own just a second ago, now the problem is how to do this with screentouch like tablets, i want to touch the div once to modify height and again in any content inside to move to that link like normal. (the first click only move the tab but never open the link.9

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help much on this one, but you could try hiding the link and showing a textlabel instead and use :active pseudoclass to hide the label and show the link instead...however that kind of breaks it for the other browsers which trigger :active only while you hold the mousebutton down.

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery solution** (it doesn't slow your application):

http://jsfiddle.net/EtBKx/16/

I wrote just the core syntax, now you can replace the .css with .animate and add all the effects you need.

---

**CSS3 solution** (not compatible with all browsers)

http://jsfiddle.net/EtBKx/22/

---

EDIT:

You can refer at [this link](http://return-true.com/2010/06/css-transforms-and-transitions-practical-examples/)